# How to access the object in 3d pdf using Javascript in Adobe Acrobat Reader 2017?

Tags: javascript, pdf, 3d, acrobat

I have an object in 3D PDF, from which I need to save the object as an image by animating the 3d model object at various angles. 
Using https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_3d_api_reference.pdf I tried to access the object in Javascript and animate it, I was unable to get the 3d model object itself, could someone help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 3D annotation is the only one on the first page of the PDF the code snippet will return the 3D model and then you can use the object properties and methods.

```
var model3D = this.getAnnots3D(0)[0].context3D
```

Comment: I get an error `this.getAnnots3D is not a function`

Comment: Can you post the PDF?

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot post the pdf, it is kind of proprietary info. Could you try on some online 3d pdf. My ultimate goal is to animate the 3D object in the pdf using some commands and save the object orientation as images. It would be a great help if you could help me with the code.